# margin-botton doesnt work in layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need move up the button "Choose a picture" I try with margin-button but doesn't work. Look the picture and the code. Any help? I dont know how solve this problem. Maybe Padding, but I tried and doesn't work too.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" style="@style/activity_main" android:background="#FFFFFF">

<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_picture"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgProfileBackground"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/background_profile"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="@string/choose_picture"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSelectPicture"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_change_picture"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="119dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.76"
            android:baselineAligned="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_weight="0.06"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Last Name"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_weight="0.28"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/lastName"
                android:layout_weight="3.98"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.88">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Phone"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_weight="0.01"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_weight="0.06"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/upload"
        android:id="@+id/updateButton"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_save_changes"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try removing the android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" and adding android:paddingBottom="25dip" to the parent RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

The line that has layout_alignParentBottom is forcing the button to stay at the bottom of the parent element, no matter how you set the margins.

You can take out the line with android:layout_alignParentBottom, and replace that line with android:layout_below"@+id/imgProfile".  Then you will be able to use android:layout_marginTop successfully.

Here is an example of the corrected code for the layout that you want:

```
  <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="choose picture"
                android:id="@+id/buttonSelectPicture"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgProfile"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>
```